# How to use JGit to get the URL of a particular github branch?

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

Is it possible to get URL of a Github branch using JGit?

I know that in JGit, we can get the remote origin URL by the below line

```
String url = repository.getConfig().getString( "remote", "origin", "url" );
```

For Eg.: I have a repo with URL "https://github.com/organizationname/reponame".

In this repo, I do have a branch named "branch1".

- Is it possible to get the URL of the branch using **JGit**? (i.e., "https://github.com/organizationname/reponame/tree/branch1")
- Also, is it available in normal command line as well (**git cli**)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JGit is a Java implementation of Git, and not related to GitHub at all. For Java (and other) implementations of the GitHub API see here: https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/